# Multiple relations parent/child with multiple levels

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, relational-database, relationships

I have a MySQL table named `companies` like this:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| id_comp | comp_name | id_parent |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|       1 | comp1     |      NULL |
|       2 | comp2     |         1 |
|       3 | comp3     |         2 |
|       4 | comp4     |         2 |
|       5 | comp5     |         2 |
|       6 | comp6     |         1 |
|       3 | comp3     |         6 |
|       5 | comp5     |         6 |
|       7 | comp7     |         6 |
|       4 | comp4     |         6 |
|       8 | comp8     |         4 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Each company may have multiple parents (ex: `comp3`, which is child of `comp2` and `comp6`), each parent may have multiple childs and each child can be a parent itself of multiple childs and so on... So, it can have unlimited levels (relations).

I researched several solutions (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818694/SQL-queries-to-manage-hierarchical-or-parent-child, http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), but I don't think it fits my the problem since the same company (based on `id_comp` column) can have multiple parents.

I have two questions regarding this:

1. Is this the right approach if I have thousands of relations (scalable) ?
2. How do I, given a `name` (which is unique, based on `id_comp`) query to select its brothers (same parent_id), its direct parent(s), and its direct child(s).

Comment: You only care about direct parents/children?  You don't need all the ancestors/descendants?

Comment: @Jerrad, just the direct up and down (parents and childs), and the brothers.

Comment: You say `name` is unique, yet I see it multiple times, hence not `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql isn't the best choice if you need to work with hierarchical data (getting all ancestors/descendants can be tricky).  But if all you care about is finding direct parents/children, your table should be fine (although I might break it out into separate Company and CompanyParent tables so that the company name isn't entered multiple times).

This would give you brothers:

```
select name
from companies 
where id_parent in (select id_parent from companies where id_comp = @company_id)
and id_comp <> @company_id
group by name;
```

This would give you direct parents:

```
select p.name
from companies p
join companies c on p.id = c.id_parent
where c.id_comp = @company_id
group by c.name;
```

This would give you direct children:

```
select c.name
from companies p
join companies c on p.id = c.id_parent
where p.id_comp = @company_id
group by c.name;
```

Comment: Thank you much I could integrate it with Union between the three queries. How do I avoid from repeting itself when selecting the brothers?

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple "many:many" relationship.  However, you have a restriction that is not really relevant (nor checkable) in that there are no loops.

```
CREATE TABLE Relations (
    id_comp ...,
    id_parent ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_comp, id_parent),  -- for reaching "up"
    INDEX(id_parent, id_comp)         -- for reaching "down"
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This will scale to millions, probably billions, of relations.  Since a `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition, `UNIQUE` and an `INDEX`, it prevents duplicate relations (`1` is a parent of `2` only once) and provides an efficient way to traverse one direction.

Use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY` when necessary.  Do not use `IN ( SELECT ...)`, it tends to be slow.

My Siblings:

```
SELECT DISTINCT their_kids.*
    FROM Relations AS me
    JOIN Relations AS my_parents  ON my_parents.id_comp = me.id_parent
    JOIN Relations AS their_kids  ON their_kids.id_parent = parents.id_comp
    WHERE         me.id_comp = @me
      AND their_kids.id_comp != @me;
```

My (immediate) Parents:

```
SELECT my_parents.*
    FROM Relations AS me
    JOIN Relations AS my_parents  ON my_parents.id_comp = me.id_parent
    WHERE me.id_comp = @me;
```

My (immediate) Children:

```
SELECT my_kids.*
    FROM Relations AS me
    JOIN Relations AS my_kids  ON my_kids.id_parent = me.id_comp
    WHERE me.id_comp = @me;
```

Aunts, uncles, first cousins would be a bit messier.  All ancestors or descendants would be much messier, and should be done with a loop in application code or a Stored Procedure.

Comment: This does a lot of sense, I will test this today, and I will get back to you. Thank you

Comment: Just one more question that neither of you guys included in your anwsers. How would the three selects be joined, with union?

Comment: `JOIN` is like "and"; `UNION` is like "or".  If you want the  children and also the parents, `UNION` together my two queries.  OK, English is confusing as what "and" means.  Mathematics is perfectly clear on "and" ("intersect") versus "or".

Comment: @Vishnu - In MySQL, you can store values in `@variables`.  Perhaps Postgres does not use that syntax.  Every vendor has a lot of differences in SQL compared to other vendors.

Comment: okay. Syntax is slightly different regarding variables. Anyway getting error in the where clause. Changed it to WHERE me.id_comp = @me.id_comp but not returning any results. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Vishnu - In that context `x.y` syntax (in at least MySQL) refers to `table_name.column_name`.  MySQL does not let you put a table name into `@me`,

Comment: When i execute the first query it throws  " Unknown column 'their_kids' in 'where clause' " and second and third query returns no result. I have added the seed data and trying on mysql.

Comment: @Vishnu - oops.  `me.id_comp`

Comment: I hope I have given you enough hints that you can figure out the rest.

Comment: @RickJames Hi, to support pagination, the results from all the three queries are combined ,sorted on name and spliced to fulfill the limit (like 50). What would the better approach be (to scale for millions), putting limits(50) for each of the three queries and then doing the above?

Comment: @Anish - Are you suggesting a million rows being paged through 50 at a time?  You would be better off with one page per family and _immediate_ descendants.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, like for a given company, i want to display its parents, children & siblings. But only 50 at a time. One page at a time will not give a clear picture for that particular company.