# How do i retrieve brothers, parents and children from sql table

Tags: javascript, sqlite, graph, sequelize.js

I have sqlite table like this

a) node table

```
+------------------+------------------+
|         id       |       name       |     
|-------------------------------------+
|7c7d1ea6-8a9b-4abe| paradise island  |            
+------------------+------------------+
|7c2fdb84-6d12-4cdb| banana tree      |                                            
+------------------+------------------+
|44c034c5-cad0-4f69| yellow banana    |               
+------------------+------------------+
```

b) edges table

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
| id |       org_id       |       parent       |     
|----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 7c7d1ea6-8a9b-4abe |       null         |              
+------------------+---------------------------+
|  2 | 7c2fdb84-6d12-4cdb | 7c7d1ea6-8a9b-4abe |                                                
+------------------+---------------------------+
|  3 | 44c034c5-cad0-4f69 | 7c2fdb84-6d12-4cdb |               
+------------------+---------------------------+
```

given a name (which is unique, based on name) I need a query to select its brothers (same parent_id), its direct parent(s), and its direct child(s).

@jerrad provided a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43894945/1451422) but then it doesn't retrieve the brothers, parent(s) and children at the same time. is this possible?

i've seen some examples on recursive CTEs but i do not know how to go about it. I'm using sequelize ORM and sqlite database.

On the other hand, Looking at [@Jerrad's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892661/multiple-relations-parent-child-with-multiple-levels), I could push the results into one array having in mind that it has to be sorted in order of name plus pagination support is required.

I'll appreciate anyone who can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: here's the link to jerrad's solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892661/multiple-relations-parent-child-with-multiple-levels

Comment: In real life, the number of siblings/children varies for each parent.  So you would not be able to have a single row showing all siblings (e.g. 2 for one row, 3 for the other row, etc.) unless you put them all in a single column, e.g., as with group_concat().  Unless you mean to have each sibling/child in a separate row.  So, please show a better example (there are no siblings in your current example), and your expected output for each case.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound).